# Matlab speech-to-text IBM Watson e

Tags: matlab, speech-to-text

I am using the MATLAB [speech2text](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/65266-speech2text) function to try to convert audio to text with IBM Watson third party.

I have a JSON file with my credentials in the same folder the .m code.

I tried running it without the keywords extra feature, but that doesn't make a difference. I am at a loss as to what else to try as it is almost line-for-line the example that they give in their documentation.  I am not familiar with JSON files so I am worried that could be set up wrong, but followed step by step instructions.

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('filelocation/file.wav');

speechObjectIBM = speechClient('IBM','keywords',"Tom, Jenny, RJ, Andy, Jason, Jeff",'keywords_threshold',0.5);

speechObjectIBM.Options

tableOut = speech2text(speechObjectIBM,y,Fs);
```

I should get a transcript and instead get the following error:

```
Output argument "tableOut" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "BaseSpeechClient/speechToText".
```

Comment: Since the files are p coded (source-code not available), probably only the developers can tell what's wrong: https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us.html There are others in the comment section with the same problem, but no solution.